# Embedding a Sony cam in an exsting Network

Tags: camera, sony

I am currently developing a programm using the Camera Remote API from Sony.
The camera, when activating the remote functions, starts acting like some sort of Wireless Access Point itself, which is nice though for the actual usage.

However, I wonder if it is possible to embed the camera (Sony alpha7r) in an already existing network and communicate with the camera using the existing network.

Thanks for the help

L. Pieper

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when Smart Remote app is launched in A7R, the camera can only function as Wireless AP.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team